# How to specify Time to Live for POJO created with Redisson Live Objects?

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I am annotating some POJOs with @REntitty, @RId to make them available as Distributed Objects across JVMs with Redisson library/Redis.

How do i specify Time to Live for these POJOs when i create them using LiveObjectService ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the api docs and here's what i found. The RedisLiveObjectService has a method 'asRExpirable(T instance)'(link to the documentation : https://static.javadoc.io/org.redisson/redisson/3.4.1/org/redisson/api/RLiveObjectService.html#asRExpirable-T-) 
I also found this test case in the redis git repo which demonstrates the use of rexpirable objects. I hope it helps
https://github.com/redisson/redisson/blob/master/redisson/src/test/java/org/redisson/RedissonLiveObjectServiceTest.java (Look for the testExpirable() test case)

Comment: Yes, the links helped. Looks like LiveObjects (e.g. List) inside a Live Object still doesn't get expired when parent Object has been set asRExpirable.